# Specify Different width to 'View' for iPhone and iPad Xcode 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, xcode9

I have one 'View' for which i didn't add any width and it works fine in different iPhone Sizes as i have specified aspect ratio, but as i switch to iPad that 'View' stretches to take whole space in iPad i want to specify width for 'View' in iPad, has anyone done this things before ?

Comment: it's really not how you make modern **autolayout** apps, which are totally dynamic - so, you will always be going uphill, you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the aspect ratio constraint for IPad and create a suitable one for it like this

1- Un install the aspect ratio constraint , click the + icon near installed from the popup select Regular for width and height , then click add variation

[image]

2- And un Check it for RR

[image]

3- Select any IPad device in the bottom Bar , click vary for traits and make the new aspect ratio constraint as you want then click Done varying 
[image]

By this you have 2 different constraints for the aspect ratio when you run the app in IPhone or Ipad , **Note:** you can do it for any constraint you want